# Cannot display query results using cmd.ExecuteNonQuery in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, executenonquery

I have a lotto draw method which should find the winning ticket from the database of purchased tickets. But I am not able to display the results from the query. (I know this isn't how the Lotto really works, I'll come to randomizing the numbers later :P )

**draw.aspx.cs**

```
public void LottoDraw(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectionstring = "Server=C;Database=lotto;User Id=lottoadmin;Password=password;";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))  // Create connection with automatic disposal
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var tran = con.BeginTransaction())  // Open a transaction
        {
            // Create command with parameters
            string sql =
                "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblLotto ORDER BY NEWID()";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            cmd.Transaction = tran;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute the query

            tran.Commit();  // commit transaction

            Response.Write("<br />");
            Response.Write("<br />");
            Response.Write("end...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` should only be used for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UDPATE` statements that don't return values. For a `SELECT`, use `ExecuteReader()` to get back a `SqlDataReader` so you can actually **read** the results returned from the query. ADO.NET basics 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using exectue non-query.

To retrieve results you either need to use an SQLReader or an SqlDataAdapter

Personally  I find using a DataAdapter easier:

```
    DataTable t = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(DataConnectionString))
    {
         c.Open();
         // Create new DataAdapter
         using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmployeeIDs", c))     
         {
              // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
              a.Fill(t);
         }
    }
```

You can then access your data by:

```
 if(t.Rows.Count == 1){

      String val0 = t.Rows[0]["VAL0"].ToString();
      String val1 = t.Rows[0]["VAL1"].ToString();
      String val2 = t.Rows[0]["VAL2"].ToString();
      String val3 = t.Rows[0]["VAL3"].ToString();
      String val4 = t.Rows[0]["VAL4"].ToString();
      String val5 = t.Rows[0]["VAL5"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am having an error when trying to retrive the data. **The name 't' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: It sounds like your datatable is being declared on an inner scope and then being accessed on an outerscope.

Comment: I've updated my example to move the datatable to the outer scope.

Comment: my query: `SELECT TOP 1 VAL0, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4, VAL5 FROM tblLotto ORDER BY NEWID()`

Comment: It shouldn't do you should be able to access any of those fields within the datatable. Updated my answer again.